# Skip every nth element of array

Tags: arrays, julia

How can I remove every nth element from an array in julia? Let's say I have the following array: `a = [1 2 3 4 5 6]` and I want `b = [1 2 4 5]`

In javascript I would do something like:

```js
b = a.filter(e => e % 3);
```

How can it be done in Julia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question title and text ask different questions. The title asks how to skip the Nth element, whereas the Javascript code snippet details how to skip elements based on their *value*, not their index.

## Skipping by Value

We can do this using [`filter`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.filter).

```
filter((x) -> x % 3 != 0, a)
```

This is basically equivalent to your Javascript code. We can, incidentally, also use [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting).

```
a[a .% 3 .!= 0]
```

This is more akin to code you would see in array-oriented languages like MATLAB and R.

## Skipping by Index

With an extra [`enumerate`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.enumerate) call, we can get the indices to operate on.

```
map((x) -> x[2], Iterators.filter(((x) -> x[1] % 3 != 0), enumerate(a)))
```

This is roughly what you'd do in Python. `enumerate` to get the indices, `filter` to purge, then `map` to eliminate the now-unnecessary indices.

Or we can, again, use broadcasting.

```
a[(1:length(a)) .% 3 .!= 0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will update the question to be more clear but I think your examples are good enough to keep both for reference. In my case indexes was equal to value so that's why I got confused in my js example.

Comment: In the latest example you create a temp array (Vector). You can use generator to avoid temp memory allocation and write it more compact way:
`a[(1:end) .% 3 .!== 0]`

or use begin:end syntax (Julia 1.5+):

`a[(begin:end) .% 3 .!== 0]`

Comment: While the `Vector()` is unnecessary, things like `(1:end) .% 3 .!== 0` will allocate an array, although a BitVector. This version could also be written `a[eachindex(a) .% 3 .!= 0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm still learning Julia myself. I had tried `1:length(a) .% 3 .!= 0` (without parens) and concluded it didn't work. Good to know that I was wrong about that.

Comment: a[(1:end) .% 3 .!== 0] will not allocate BitArray for the case (since it is a generator inside selection).

Comment: Double check with Julia compiler, we both was wrong: Julia creates BitArray for both cases: `a[(begin:end) .% 3 .!= 0]`, `a[eachindex(a) .% 3 .!= 0]`.

Comment: Please be careful about using assuming that `1` is the first index and `length(a)` is the last index of an array. Julia arrays are allowed to start and end at any index; you should use `begin:end` to get the indices of the entire array. (Of course, if `begin` is not 1, the locations of your `.%3 .== 0` elements might not be where you expect.) C.f. https://julialang.org/blog/2017/04/offset-arrays/

Comment: Also, a much simpler way of indexing every third element is `a[begin:3:end]`

Answer (score 4):

If you need skipping by index the most elegant way is to use `InvertedIndices`

```
julia> using InvertedIndices  # or using DataFrames


julia> a[Not(3:3:end)]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 4
 5
```

As you can see all your job here is to provide a range of indices you wish to skip.

Comment: `a[Not(3:3:end)]` more flexible if we do not know the size of the `a`

Comment: This looks great since I am using DataFrames. Is there also a way to make it work with matrices? I.e. `a[Not(3:3:end), :]` to remove rows in a matrix?

Comment: Yes! it works with matrices in exactly the same way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter by the index, one convenient way is using a comprehension:

```
julia> a = 10:10:100;

julia> [a[i] for i in eachindex(a) if i % 3 != 0] |> permutedims
1×7 Matrix{Int64}:
 10  20  40  50  70  80  100

julia> vec(ans) == [a[1 + 3(j-1)÷2] for j in 1:7]
true
```

This implicitly involves `Iterators.filter`, and collects the generator. You can also use this to filter by value, although the eager `filter` is probably more efficient:

```
julia> a = 1:10;

julia> [x for x in a if x%3!=0] |> permutedims
1×7 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  4  5  7  8  10
```

Perhaps it's interesting to time all of these:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools, InvertedIndices

julia> a = rand(1000);  # filter by index

julia> i1 = @btime [$a[1 + 3(j-1)÷2] for j in 1:667];
  373.162 ns (1 allocation: 5.38 KiB)

julia> i2 = @btime $a[eachindex($a) .% 3 .!= 0];
  1.387 μs (4 allocations: 9.80 KiB)

julia> i3 = @btime [$a[i] for i in eachindex($a) if i % 3 != 0];
  3.557 μs (11 allocations: 16.47 KiB)

julia> i4 = @btime map((x) -> x[2], Iterators.filter(((x) -> x[1] % 3 != 0), enumerate($a)));
  4.202 μs (11 allocations: 16.47 KiB)

julia> i5 = @btime $a[Not(3:3:end)];
  84.333 μs (4655 allocations: 182.28 KiB)

julia> i1 == i2 == i3 == i4 == i5
true

julia> a = rand(1:99, 1000);  # filter by value

julia> v1 = @btime filter(x -> x%3!=0, $a);
  532.185 ns (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)

julia> v2 = @btime [x for x in $a if x%3!=0];
  5.465 μs (11 allocations: 16.47 KiB)

julia> v1 == v2
true
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
b = a[Bool[i %3 != 0 for i = 1:length(a)]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a[a .% 2 .!= 0]
```

please find the [link](https://code.labstack.com/uqOAexmM) with code.

Comment: This is incorrect. You are removing elements divisible by 3. You're supposed to remove every 3rd element, as per the title of the question.